# MySQL : i need hel p Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Hi I have a problem with this subquery what I would like is to know the clients with more reservations to their name if possible without using the ORDER BY .. DESC
LIMIT 1;

I have this code:

```
SELECT  c.client_id, COUNT(r.reserva_id)
    FROM reserves r
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.client_id = r.client_id
GROUP BY c.client_id
HAVING COUNT(r.reserva_id) < (SELECT COUNT(r2.reserva_id) 
                        FROM reserves r2
                     GROUP BY r2.client_id)
```

But it does not work. Can you help me

Thanks..

Comment: Please include sample data.

Comment: SELECT  c.client_id, COUNT(r.reservation_id)
    FROM reservations r
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.client_id = r.client_id
GROUP BY c.client_id
HAVING COUNT(r.reservation_id) < (SELECT COUNT(r2.reservation_id) 
                        FROM reservations r2
                     GROUP BY r2.client_id)

Comment: I'm from Spain and my DB is written in Spanish

Comment: `clients with more reservations to their name` ... please explain this, possibly by showing us data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- WITH ORDER BY COUNT(r.reserva_id) DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT  c.client_id, COUNT(r.reserva_id) `count`
FROM reserves r
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.client_id = r.client_id
GROUP BY c.client_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;

-- WITH SUB QUERIES
SELECT B.*
FROM
(SELECT  c.client_id, COUNT(r.reserva_id) `count`
FROM reserves r
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.client_id = r.client_id
GROUP BY c.client_id) B WHERE B.`count`=
(SELECT MAX(A.`count`)
FROM
(SELECT  c.client_id, COUNT(r.reserva_id) `count`
FROM reserves r
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.client_id = r.client_id
GROUP BY c.client_id) A);
```

See it [run on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/861ee9/1).

To me just go with the first query, it's simple to understand and run.

Comment: When i execute them i get this error

Table 'db_hotels.A' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

First, the `join` is not necessary for the query you have written.

Second, I can interpret your question as "clients with the most reservations".  The logic in your current query doesn't come close to this.

But for this version of the query, it would be:

```
SELECT  r.client_id, COUNT(*)
FROM reserves r
GROUP BY r.client_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM reserves r2
                   GROUP BY r2.client_id
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  );
```

If you really want to avoid `ORDER BY`/`LIMIT 1` in the subquery, you can do:

```
SELECT  r.client_id, COUNT(*)
FROM reserves r
GROUP BY r.client_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(cnt)
                   FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM reserves r2
                         GROUP BY r2.client_id
                        ) r2
                   );
```